# Custom .htaccess rules for web app

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I'm trying to undersand [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but I end up always confused with all this, so I'm asking if someone can help me with this custom rules.

My web app will use 3 kinds of pages which currently have these URLs:

- `url.com/index.php?user=name` is for the user profiles
- `url.com/index.php?page=name` is for the front-end pages (about, contact, etc...)
- `url.com/index.php?dash=name` is for logged-in area pages

But I want the first 2 to be `url.com/name` and the 3rd to be `url.com/dashboard/name`.

I guess that for the `user` and `page` I'll have first to check if page exists, then check usernames and if none of this exists, then return 404.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

These type of custom rules are defined using Regex.

Check the kind of page using RewriteCond and define RewriteRule accordingly.

Complete information is available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off having 3 URL schemes:

1. url.com/user/name
2. url.com/page/name
3. url.com/dashboard/name

If that is acceptable then you need to enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webapp/

RewriteRule ^user/(.+?)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/(.+?)/?$ index.php?PAGE=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.+?)/?$ index.php?dash=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I know, that it'll be easier/better to use `/user/` and `/page/`, but I really do want to use URLs without these two. Is it possible?

Comment: Otherwise .htaccess will always pass it to `/index.php?user=$1` and you will need to handle it inside `index.php` to load a user (if exists) or load a page.

Comment: You were right, it's actually a better method, however, your rewrite rules doesn't work. They redirect to root...

Comment: most likely above .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory. Try removing `/` before `index.php`

Comment: This is what I tried: http://snippi.com/s/yixfy3b 
Apparently it works, but for `dashboard/page` it uses the first rule when second is intended...

Comment: That is not my suggested answer actually. When you say its not working what happens? You get 404 or index.php shows wrong content?

Comment: Yup, since your code didn't work, I tried to figure out myself. I'm building the web app in local server (XAMPP), and with your code I'm always redirected to `http://localhost/` (root). With my code, the `page` rewrite seems to work fine, and `dash` works well if URL is `localhost/webapp/dashboard` with no slash at the end, but if I add a slash or a subfolder (`localhost/webapp/dashboard/name`) it sends me a `page` paramenter instead of a `dash`.

Comment: So your webapp is in $DOCUMENT_ROOT/webapp ? Where is index.php located?

Comment: Yes it is. In $DOCUMENT_ROOT too, like .htaccess.

Comment: Try my edited code above. I need to goto bed, its pretty late here.

Comment: Nope. Still has the same problem.